# Angular 2 Jax-RS with GET faster than POST

Tags: java, jax-rs, angular2-services

I have a REST application using Jax-RS and Angular 2, Apache 8.5 and Postgres database using Hibernate.

The problem is when I save a new object, the GET from my list runs before the POST run completely. Here are the codes.

tabela-servicos.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Servico } from '../servico';
import { CrudServicosService } from '../crud-servicos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabela-servicos',
  templateUrl: './tabela-servicos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabela-servicos.component.css']
})
export class TabelaServicosComponent implements OnInit {

  titulo = "Tabela de Serviços";
  servicos: Servico[] = [];

  constructor(private servicoService: CrudServicosService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('called ngOnInit')
    this.servicoService.getServicos()
        .subscribe(s => {
          console.log(s);
            this.servicos = s;
        }, erro => console.log(erro));
  }

  remover(servico: Servico){
    this.servicoService.removerServico(servico)
    .subscribe(()  => {
      let novosServicos = this.servicos.slice(0);
      let indice = novosServicos.indexOf(servico);
      novosServicos.splice(indice, 1);
      this.servicos = novosServicos;
    });
  }
}
```

form-servicos.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudServicosService } from '../../app/crud-servicos.service';
import { Servico } from '../../app/servico';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-servicos',
  templateUrl: './form-servicos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-servicos.component.css']
})
export class FormServicosComponent implements OnInit {

  titulo = "Cadastro de Servicos";
  servico: Servico;
  codigo;

  constructor(private servicoService: CrudServicosService,
              private router: Router,
              private rota:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.codigo = this.rota.snapshot.params['cod'];
    if(isNaN(this.codigo)){
      this.servico = new Servico();
    } else {
      this.servico = Object.assign({},
          this.servicoService.getServicoPorCodigo(this.codigo));
    }
  }

  salvarServico(){
    if(isNaN(this.codigo)){
      this.servicoService.adicionarServico(this.servico)
    } else {
      this.servicoService.atualizaServico(this.codigo, this.servico);
    }
//    console.log("waiting 2 seconds to return page list...");
//    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/lista']);
 //   },2000);
  }

  cancelar(){
    this.router.navigate(['/lista']);
  }
}
```

ServicoResource.java

```
package resource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import dao.ServicoDAO;
import model.Servico;

@Path("servico")
public class ServicoResource {

    private static ServicoDAO servicoDao = new ServicoDAO();

    @GET
    @Path("servicos")
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test() {
        List<Servico> serv = servicoDao.getList();
        System.out.println("GET Objectos from Jax-RS");
        System.out.println("");
        return Response.ok(serv).build();
    }

    @Path("servicos/delete/{id}")
    @DELETE
    public Response removeProduto(@PathParam("id") long id){
        System.out.println("DELETE Object ID: " + id + " Jax-RS ");
        System.out.println("");
        servicoDao.remover(id);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @POST//consume o objeto enviado pro back-end
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response adiciona(String conteudo){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Servico s = gson.fromJson(conteudo, Servico.class);
        servicoDao.salvar(s);
        System.out.println("POST Object Jax-RS");
        System.out.println("");
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
```

[image: prints from ServerLog, ConsoleBrowser and Application]

When I reload the list page, after the saved object, it appears.
When I use the code below in the form-servicos.component.ts class, it works, but I know this is a bad practice.

```
 console.log ("waiting 2 seconds to return page list ...");
 setTimeout (() => {
   This.router.navigate (['/ list']);
}, 2000);
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem from the list being requested before the object is persisted ???

Comment: `service.save(...).subscribe(() => navigateToList());`

Comment: Yes, Thank U man

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This was solved.

```
adicionarServico(servico: Servico){
    console.log("Called persist POST "+JSON.stringify(servico));
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/servico', JSON.stringify(servico), {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

I changed my crud-service.ts to return an Observable < Responde > and using it in:

```
salvarServico(){
    this.servicoService.adicionarServico(this.servico)
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log("Saved Success");
        this.router.navigate(['/lista']);
      });
  }
```